# Setting wallpaper in Android

Tags: java, android, wallpaper

I am developing a simple app that sets wallpapers based on user input.
I am missing code for setting wallpapers.
I have been looking for it in lots of websites in vain.
Can anybody post a sample code that sets as a wallpaper as a drawable that is saved in the `res` folder?

Comment: It's all in the documentation:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/WallpaperManager.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Works on Android 1.5 and above

```
public void setWallpaper() {
  Context context = this.getBaseContext(); 
  Bitmap mBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), mImageIds[pos]);

  context.setWallpaper(mBitmap);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much !!!
do u know by any chance how I can solve the pixelation problems.
I heard that the app: wallpaper set and save produces super crisp wallpapers , does it just use crop method to adjust the wallpaper to the screen ?

Thanks a lot once more

Comment: Can't say about that ... I  will have to search before making a comment to it

Answer (score 2):

u can try

```
InputStream inputStream = getResources().openRawResource(wallpaperResource);
Bitmap setWallToDevice = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);

try {
getApplicationContext().setWallpaper(setWallToDevice);
} catch (IOException e) {
// TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

however this method is deprecated so u can use

```
try {
WallpaperManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).setResource(wallpaperResource);
} catch (IOException e){
e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here how we can set Wallpaper from our android application

**MainActivity.Java**

```
public class AlarmActivity extends Activity{



       @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
           setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



            WallpaperManager myWallpaperManager
                    = WallpaperManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext());


                    try {
                        myWallpaperManager.setImageResource(R.raw.sample);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

    }
}
```

**Manifest.xml**

you should provide this permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_WALLPAPER" />
```